# How to show $d(x,y)= \sqrt{d_1(x_1,y_1)^2+d_2(x_2,y_2)^2}$ is a metric?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

$d_1(x_1,y_1)$ and  $d_2(x_2,y_2)$ are metric on $X$ and $d(x,y)$ is defined as:
$$d(x,y)= \sqrt{d_1(x_1,y_1)^2+d_2(x_2,y_2)^2}.$$
I am trying to show this is a metric. Can you give me some clue about proving the triangle inequality for $d$ ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the connection between $x,x_1,$ and $x_2$? Ditto for $y,y_1,$ and $y_2$? I assume that you're trying to show that $d$ is a metric on $X^2,$ but it would be better if you made that explicit.

Comment: $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the function $f(a,b) = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ on $[0,\infty)\times [0,\infty)$. Then

1. $f(a,b) \le f(c,d)$ whenever $a \le c$ and $b\le d$, and
2. $f(a + c,b + d) \le f(a,b) + f(c,d)$,

where Property $2$ follows from the triangle inequality for vectors on $\Bbb R^2$. Given $x = (x_1,x_2)$, $y = (y_1,y_2)$, and $z = (z_1,z_2)$ in $X^2$,

\begin{align}
d(x,z) &= f(d_1(x_1,z_1), d_2(x_2,z_2))\\
&\le f(d_1(x_1,y_1) + d_1(y_1,z_1),d_2(x_2,y_2) + d_2(y_2,z_2)) \tag{i}\\
&\le f(d_1(x_1,y_1),d_2(x_2,y_2)) + f(d_1(y_1,z_1),d_2(y_2,z_2) \tag{ii}\\
&= d(x,y) + d(y,z)
\end{align}

Here, $(i)$ follows from Property 1. and the triangle inequalities for $d_1$ and $d_2$. Using the Property 2., we obtain (ii). Therefore, $d$ satisfies the triangle inequality.

Comment: How can we prove for $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$?

Comment: how can we prove property 2 ?

Comment: Consider the vectors $(a,b)$, $(c,d)$ in $\Bbb R^2$. Then $\|(a,b)\| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = f(a,b)$, $\|(c,d)\| = \sqrt{c^2 + d^2} = f(c,d)$, and $$\|(a,b) + (c,d)\| = \|(a + c,b + d)\| = \sqrt{(a + c)^2 + (b + d)^2} = f(a + c,b + d)$$ Since $\|(a,b) + (b,c)\| \le \|(a,b)\| + \|(c,d)\|$, it follows that $f(a + c,b + d) \le f(a,b) + f(c,d)$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
d(x,z)&=\left(\sum d_i(x_i,z_i)^2\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq\left(\sum(d_i(x_i,y_i)+d_i(y_i,z_i))^2\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\left(\sum d_i(x_i,y_i)^2+2\sum d_i(x_i,y_i)d_i(y_i,z_i)+\sum d_i(y_i,z_i)^2\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq\left[\sum d_i(x_i,y_i)^2+2\left(\sum d_i(x_i,y_i)^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum d_i(y_i,z_i)^2\right)^{1/2}+\sum d_i(y_i,z_i)^2\right]^{1/2}\\
&=\left\{\left[\left(\sum d_i(x_i,y_i)^2\right)^{1/2}+\left(\sum d_i(y_i,z_i)^2\right)^{1/2}\right]^2\right\}^{1/2}\\
&=\left(\sum d_i(x_i,y_i)^2\right)^{1/2}+\left(\sum d_i(y_i,z_i)^2\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)
\end{align*}