# Let $(X,d_{x}),(Y,d_{y})$ two metric spaces. Prove that $\sqrt{d_{x}(x_{1},x_{2})^{2}+d_{y}(y_{1},y_{2})^{2}}$ is a metric.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

d is defined by : $d: (X\times Y)\times (X\times Y)\rightarrow \left [ 0, \infty  \right ] : ((x_{1},y_{1}),(x_{2},y_{2})) \mapsto \sqrt{d_{x}(x_{1},x_{2})^{2}+d_{y}(y_{1},y_{2})^{2}}$. I have proven everything but the triangle inequality condition which I'm asking for your help with. It also gives me the hint to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ which is: $\forall a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}: ab+cd\leq \sqrt{a^{2}+c^{2}}\sqrt{b^{2}+d^{2}}$.

Comment: Have you tried to square the inequality you are trying to prove?

Comment: Some older posts I was able to find:
[If $d_1(x,y)$ and $d_2(x,y)$ are metrics, prove that $d'(x,y)= \sqrt{d_1^2(x,y)+d_2^2(x,y)}$ is a metric.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1353126), 
[How to show $d(x,y)= \sqrt{d_1(x_1,y_1)^2+d_2(x_2,y_2)^2}$ is a metric?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1211661)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the triangle inequality may present difficulties:

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\|(u,v)\|_2=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$ define a norm. In particular,
$$\|(u+u',v+v')\|_2\leq\|(u,v)\|_2+\|(u',v')\|_2$$

With $u=d_X(x,x'')$, $u'=d_X(x'',x)$, $v=d_Y(y,y'')$ and $v'=d_Y(y'',y)$
\begin{align}
d((x,y),(x',y')):&=\sqrt{d^2_X(x,x')+d^2_Y(y,y')}\leq\sqrt{(d_X(x,x'')+d_X(x'',x))^2+ (d_Y(y,y'')+d_Y(y'',y'))^2}\\
&=\|(u+u',v+v')\|_2\leq\|(u,v)\|_2+\|(u',v')\|_2\\
&=\sqrt{d^2_X(x,x'')+d^2_Y(y'',y)} + \sqrt{d^2_X(x'',x')+d^2_Y(y'',y')}\\
&=d((x,y),(x'',y'')) + d(x'',y''),(x',y'))
\end{align}